# how to validate session in Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have implemented  HandlerInterceptorAdapter in my application  ,in preHandle method i am checking whether session have a "user" attribute or not .If there is null then i am sending redirect to  login page.

```
if ( request.getSession().getAttribute("user")==null) {  
            System.out.println("hello");
            response.sendRedirect("login.htm");
            return true;
            }

        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
```

when am opening any url in browser  am getting a message 
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

what should i do please suggest me!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String indexView(HttpServletRequest request){

if ( request.getSession().getAttribute("user")==null) {  
    System.out.println("hello");
     return "redirect:/login.html"
    }
else 
   return "index";
}
```

Frankly, I believe you should use Spring Security. This is much better, less buggy, more secure and rapid way to implement Web Container security using Spring.

Hope it helps.